# Firebase: How to add an index for a nested field?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a `locations-orders` table that looks like this:

```
{
  "0BW3H9T3R7HJB" : {
    "orders" : {
      "01750ea0-4980-4bc4-58b2-988c02324e671478636582396" : {
        "created_at" : 1478636560000,
      },
      "01750ea0-4980-4bc4-58b2-988c02324e671478636582483" : {
        "created_at" : 1478636560000,
      }
    }
}
```

Each location-orders node has an `orders` node with multiple keys/objects. Those objects have a `created_at` field on it.

I added this to my database Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "merchantId"
    },
    "merchants": {
      ".indexOn": "locations"
    },
    "locations-orders": {
      ".indexOn": ["orders/created_at"]
    }
  }
}
```

However, Firebase is still complaining that I'm missing an index:

```
Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "created_at" at /locations-orders/1JS53G0TT5ZQD/orders to your security rules for better performance
```

Am I supposed to run something to create the index? Or is it written incorrectly?

=== UPDATE ===

I changed my file to look into:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "merchantId"
    },
    "merchants": {
      ".indexOn": "locations"
    },
    "locations-orders": {
      "$location_id": {
        ".indexOn": ["orders/created_at", "orders/status_updated_at"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I still get the same warning:

```
Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "created_at" at /locations-orders/1JS53G0TT5ZQD/orders to your security rules for better performance
```

Comment: You've included pictures of the JSON tree and rules in your question. Please replace these with the actual JSON and rules as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: sure will do!!!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated!

Answer (score 4):

If you look at your data structure, there is no `orders/created_at` under `/location-order/$orderId`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "merchantId"
    },
    "merchants": {
      ".indexOn": "locations"
    },
    "locations-orders": {
      "$someid": {
        ".indexOn": ["orders/created_at"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: does it matter what what i write for `$someid`?

Comment: Nope. It's just like a variable name in your actual code: as long as you use the same value inside the rule (not needed here), the actual name doesn't matter.

Comment: i don't have to run any command or anything? I updated it to look like that but it still shows the error

Comment: Indexes are created immediately when you save the rules that defined them. If you're still having problems: can you reproduce them in a minimal jsbin? That will make it easier to get a complete picture.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "merchantId"
    },
    "merchants": {
      ".indexOn": "locations"
    },
    "locations-orders": {
      "orders": {
        "$orderid": {
          ".indexOn": "created_at"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this method is works for me
i index multiple child and also nested child

[firebase nested child indexing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8EWg.png)

`

Comment: Please post your code as (properly formatted) text, not as an image. (You can write two lines a three backticks (```) and put your code between them.)